# I am having problems while starting npm start for react

Tags: reactjs, npm-install, npm-start

Starting the development server...

events.js:291
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
^

Error: spawn powershell ENOENT
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:268:19)
at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:464:16)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:274:12)
at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:464:16)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) {
errno: -4058,
code: 'ENOENT',
syscall: 'spawn powershell',
path: 'powershell',
spawnargs: [
'-NoProfile',
'-NonInteractive',
'–ExecutionPolicy',
'Bypass',
'-EncodedCommand',
'UwB0AGEAcgB0ACAAIgBgACIAaAB0AHQAcAA6AC8ALwBsAG8AYwBhAGwAaABvAHMAdAA6ADMAMAAwADAAYAAiACIA'
]
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! my-app@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the my-app@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-09-01T11_15_01_794Z-debug.log

Comment: the cryptic `ENOENT` actually mean: ERROR NO ENTITY, it's basically the 404 not found of your terminal.

You have a file that is not found somewhere, maybe you renamed the entry point or something ?

Comment: This question needs to be more specific.